# Dynamically Adding ComboBox/Text Box to DataGridView Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, datagridview, rows

I am not very experienced working with Windows Forms. I have a certain requirement that is I want to add rows to DataGridView and the columns have either a ComboBox or a text box. Could any one please guide me on how to add "Control" columns to DataGridView rows. So basically I should be able to add as many as rows with my controls.Combo boxes are cascading as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do:

- Add a ComboBox*Column*
- Change the value of this column for each row

What you can't do:

- Have different ColumnTypes for multiple rows

That means:

You can't decide for each Row which type of column should be used. When you need a combobox for a specific row you cannot add it to a datagridview containing rows which all need only textboxcolumns.

What you can do is the following:

At runtime, there is a memberfunction called [DataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQFjAAahUKEwitzJGf_dfHAhUGvBQKHRhND2w&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fde-de%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.forms.datagridview.getcelldisplayrectangle(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNGLvrhoZze0ImiU4MKOWLhJt8yBrA&sig2=QZJvS9tbku5_91-zTJOt7w&bvm=bv.101800829,d.d24). Whith this method you can get the bounds of a specific cell at runtime. Lets imagine that you have the combobox only applied on this one specific row. Here's the scheme:

```
void OnSelectionChanged(Object sender, ChangedEventArgs e){
    if(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex == 4){
        // Show one single ComboBox in the specified Cell in the Row 4 (actually Row 3 because RowIndex is zero-based)

        if(this.Controls.Contains(ComboBox1))
            this.Controls.Remove(ComboBox1);

        ComboBox ComboBox1 = gcnew ComboBox();
        // Define the properties of your combobox:
        ComboBox1.Text = "Choose an Option...";
        ComboBox1.AutoSize = false; // Important, because you will change the size programmatically
        // ...


        // Get the boundaries of the desired cell
        Rectangle CellBounds = DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(
            /*ColumnIndex*/ 1,
            /*RowIndex*/ DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex,
            /*CutOverflow*/ false);

        // By applying size and location to the combobox you make sure it is displayed on the cell
        ComboBox1.Size = CellBounds.Size;
        ComboBox1.Location = CellBounds.Location;

        // Add the ComboBox to your Controls in order to get it rendered when your window is shown
        this.Controls.Add(ComboBox1);
}
```

Now your Combobox is displayed on the Cell you specified at `GetCellDisplayRectangle( ColumnIndex, RowIndex, CutOverflow)`. Of course this code can be optimized further, as everytime you select another cell a new combobox is created and added to your controlcontainer. This will propably use much memory after many selections. But it will work.

Comment: Well Thanks for the reply. Most of the time all the rows' columns will be of same type except one column that could be either a combo box column or text box column and that depends on value selected in some column's combo box.

Comment: @V.B Well,with the code supplied above you can easily accomplish your needs. As i suppose you know how to retrieve the values of cells in other rows, you can add these decisions to the code.